# Calculating event lengths that cross time changes

Tags: calendar, calculated-column, date-time

I have a calculated field to work out the length of an event in days, as follows:

```
=DATEDIF([Start Time],[End Time],"d")
```

I live in the UK and we're currently on BST; so if I create an event in GMT after the clocks change it calculates the day as one less than it actually is.

More intresting if I set the time as UTC: Universal coordinated time it is wrong for the whole year not just when the clocks are changed,  IF I select UTC+1 or UTC-1 or other time zones howerver it calcualted correctly.  It seems strange that if this is a bug it has not been picked up yet.  Can anyone replicate?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ROUNDDOWN function.  You might want to take a look at [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) of calculated references available, just used it a few minutes ago to change up some display logic using IF and ISERROR.

Comment: I did try this and could not get what I wanted.  I think the problem is the dateif allready rounds down to the highest whole day value. I have now edit my question however as allwasy calculated wrong under UTC.  I am starting to think this is bug in SP.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked out why UTC time does not work but as a work around am using

```
ROUNDUP([End Time]-[Start Time],0)
```

And it seems to be working.  I need to test it works across all time zones first and not just UTC.

I am going to contact MS as i think the UTC thing must be a bug.  Would like to know if someone can re-produce.  I am using Search sever express version of SP.